# Trying to read amount of special characters in Text file

Tags: java

In this situation I cannot use a for loop or a do while loop. I am in a intro programming class and cannot seem to get anything to work for me, I am in need of some help. What we are having to do is to take a text file make java read it and find out how many left parenthesis, right parenthesis, commas, periods, exclamation points, question mark, asterisk, and how many vowels are in the text file. The problem that I am facing with this is that I cannot seem to get it to update the counters correcting and I also cannot get the input.hasNext() as a variable. Anything helps, thanks in advance.

Code here:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.*;

public class PP5_15
{
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException
{
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("Chp5.txt")); 
input.useDelimiter("");

int R_ParCount = 0;
int L_ParCount = 0;
int ComCount = 0;
int PerCount = 0;
int ExCount = 0;
int QuCount = 0;
int AstCount = 0;
int VowCount = 0;
int NumCount = 0; 

while(input.hasNext() == true)
{
  if(input.next().contains("("))
  R_ParCount++;
  else if (input.next().contains(")"))
  L_ParCount++;
}
while(input.hasNext())
{
  if(input.next().contains("'"))
  ComCount++; 
  else if(input.next().contains("%"))
  PerCount++;
          }

System.out.println("Amount of Right Parenthese: "+R_ParCount); 
System.out.println("Amount of Left Parenthese: "+L_ParCount);
System.out.println("Amount of Commas: "+ComCount); 
System.out.println("Amount of Percent Signs: "+PerCount); 
System.out.println("Amount of Exclamation Points: "+ExCount); 
System.out.println("Amount of Question Marks: "+QuCount);
System.out.println("Amount of Astric Count: "+AstCount); 
System.out.println("Amount of Vowels: "+VowCount); 
System.out.println("Amount of Numeric Places are: "+NumCount);

}
}
```

Comment: You forgot to mention what problem you are facing

Comment: You are calling `input.next()` too many times.

Comment: how to I go about not calling it as many times as I have? I tried everything to my knowledge.

Comment: You could simply assign` String word = input.next()` and replace each call with word. only reassign word when you want the next token.

Comment: First, start with indenting your code correcty. Then, when the first loop is finished, it is because there is no next any more. So the second loop can't be entered. You have to do it in one loop.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to store the value returned by `next()` and then do the comparisons:

```
input.useDelimiter("");

while(input.hasNext())
{
    // Get the next letter and convert to char
    char c = input.next().charAt(0);
    if (c == '(') {
        R_ParCount++;
    }
    else if (c == ')') {
        L_ParCount++;
    }
    else if (c == ',') {
        ComCount++; 
    }
    else if (c == '%') {
        PerCount++;
    }
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: This isn't going to work. It'll only examine the first character of each word

Comment: @KaranModi Can you be more specific?

Comment: input.next().charAt(0) will only compare the first character of each sequence seperated by a space

Comment: @KaranModi Yes, but in your original code you have `input.useDelimiter("");` which will read one char at a time. I can modify it to work without that.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class CountChars
{
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException
    {
        // fine so far
        Scanner input = new Scanner (new File("meanVarianceRange.sh"));
        input.useDelimiter("");

        // counting everything is more easy, than counting 10 different things    
        int[] charcount = new int [256];
        // except for the vowels, which is aeiou=5 + 5 (uppercase)
        int vowels = 0;
        // not to mention 10 ciphers, if I understood correctly
        int numerics = 0;

        while (input.hasNext ())
        {
            char c = input.next ().charAt (0);
            // we use the char as index into our array and just increment
            ++charcount [c];
            // but for the vowels, we count them as group, too
            if ("aeiouAEIOU".contains ("" + c))
                ++vowels;
            // in contrast, digits are ordered in the ascii table, 
            // so we can express them as >= '0' and <= '9'
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
                ++numerics;
        }
        // see, how the char itself makes the code self commenting: 
        System.out.println ("Amount of Right Parenthese: "   + charcount[')']);
        System.out.println ("Amount of Left Parenthese: "    + charcount['(']);
        System.out.println ("Amount of Commas: "             + charcount[',']);
        System.out.println ("Amount of Percent Signs: "      + charcount['%']);
        System.out.println ("Amount of Exclamation Points: " + charcount['!']);
        System.out.println ("Amount of Question Marks: "     + charcount['?']);
        System.out.println ("Amount of Astric Count: "       + charcount['*']);
        System.out.println ("Amount of Vowels: "             + vowels);
        // (charcount['a'] + charcount['a'] + charcount['e'] + charcount['i'] + charcount['o'] + charcount['u']));
        System.out.println ("Amount of Numeric Places are: " + numerics);
    }
}
```

Since the method 'contains' in String expects a String, we have to use this special transformation from char to String (of length 1), to find our char: `.contains ("" + c)`. Well - there are alternatives, like indexOf and testing for >= 0.

Characters can flawlessly be converted into ints (but not the other way round). That's why we can use the char itself as index into our int-array, which contains as value of charcount['x'] the number of increments, we performed at that index.

Note, that I changed the input file name, to match something on my drive.

Test:

```
Amount of Right Parenthese: 11
Amount of Left Parenthese: 11
Amount of Commas: 0
Amount of Percent Signs: 1
Amount of Exclamation Points: 1
Amount of Question Marks: 1
Amount of Astric Count: 7
Amount of Vowels: 43
Amount of Numeric Places are: 19
```